# List is returning with two sets of square brackets from sql executeInsert

Tags: sql, jdbc, groovy

I am working on a groovy script which uses the result of an sql exceuteInsert in the next insert statement executed.

The list returned from the executeInsert has two sets of squarebrackets around it, which is causing sql syntax errors. I am unsure why it is returning with two sets of brackets and if there is a way of removing both.

I have managed to remove one set of brackets using a join. My code is as follows:

```
db.withTransaction {

      def ticketResultList
      parsedTicketData.each { ticket ->
        String ticketQuery = "INSERT INTO ticket" + "(name, summary) VALUES" + "('${ticket.name}','${ticket.summary}')"
        def ticketResult = db.executeInsert(ticketQuery)
        ticketResultList = ticketResult.join(",")
      }

      parsedStatusData.each { status ->

        String ticketStatusQuery = "INSERT INTO ticket_status" + "(status, status_date, ticket_id, version) VALUES" + "('${status.status}','${status.statusDate}', ${ticketResultList}, 1)"
        db.executeInsert(ticketStatusQuery)

      }
```

The following is the sql error that is being received: Rolling back due to: Incorrect integer value: [31041] for column 'ticket_id' at row 1

Comment: you are parsing the ticketResultList itself and therefor it is surrounded with squared brackets, try getting to an item in the list.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, would that be like iterating the list within the insert: ${it.ticketResultList}

Comment: I have tried the following, but it still results in square brackets around the list item: 
ticketResultList.each { result ->
    parsedStatusData.each { status ->

        String ticketStatusQuery = "INSERT INTO ticket_status" + "(status, status_date, ticket_id, version) VALUES" + "('${status.status}','${status.statusDate}', ${result}, 1)"
        db.executeInsert(ticketStatusQuery)

      }
}

Comment: Why are you building your statement up by adding strings together?

Comment: Looks like you changed the collection you are iterating over.
I would recommend using List::pop() or any other method that will get the specific item in the list that you need.

Comment: I was adding strings as these were on multiple lines in my code. The way this is working I need to iterate through those list results not just access specific values, which appears to be working, however, I am still getting back those values with square brackets surrounding them. Also wouldn't pop just remove the final item from the list?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the code or motivation behind the code /and without reading the comments too!) I'd write something like this:

```
db.withTransaction {

  def ticketResultList = []
  parsedTicketData.each { ticket ->
    def ticketQuery = "INSERT INTO ticket" + "(name, summary) VALUES" + "('${ticket.name}','${ticket.summary}')"
    def ticketResult = db.executeInsert(ticketQuery)
    ticketResultList << ticketResult
  }

  parsedStatusData.each { status ->

    def ticketStatusQuery = "INSERT INTO ticket_status" + "(status, status_date, ticket_id, version) VALUES" + "('${status.status}','${status.statusDate}', ${ticketResultList.flatten().join(',')}, 1)"
    db.executeInsert(ticketStatusQuery)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information from [Groovy executeInsert](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#executeInsert%28groovy.lang.GString%29).

I'm assuming:

your table ticket returns one autogerarated key

the lists parsedStatusData and parsedTicketData have the same length and corresponding entries on the same possition.

```
db.withTransaction {
  parsedTicketData.each { ticket ->
     def INS1 = "INSERT INTO ticket (name, summary) VALUES (${ticket.name},${ticket.summary})"
     def ticketResult = db.executeInsert(INS1)
     ticketResultList << ticketResult[0][0] /* get the 1st returned value */
  }  
  parsedStatusData.eachWithIndex { status, i ->
    def INS2 = """INSERT INTO ticket_status (status, status_date, ticket_id, version) 
                  VALUES (${status.status},${status.statusDate}, ${ticketResultList[i]}, 1)"""
    db.executeInsert(INS2)
  }  
}
```

Note also that I reformulated your SQL strings, this is not only more compact, but leads also to the use of bind varibles. The produced SQL is something like

```
INSERT INTO ticket (name, summary) VALUES (:1,:2) RETURNING  ID INTO :3
```